# Disable future dates in UWP calendar control

Tags: uwp

I have claim application where we need to disable future dates in calendar control, How to set maximum date as todays date in UWP calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the MaxDate property. More info found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.maxdate#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarView_MaxDate